# Mac address table ,packet tracer

Tags: networking

I connected two pcs to a switch in packet tracer  , no ip addresses at all.and on switch cli I put a show mac address-table command,why there is nothing shown in the table?how does the switch so learn mac addresses?any one helps,please.I am a beginner in netwroking ,thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

When PC send a frame switch learning his MAC address via looking in frame header and checking source MAC address.

Comment: you can also click up arrow to thanks us and choose which answer answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

A switch learns MAC-port associations by inspecting the source address of frames received on a port (*self-learning MAC bridge*).

If a node doesn't send *any* frame (which may be the case if IP is deactivated and nothing else is active) the switch can't learn its MAC address.

Comment: But when I connect another switch to the first switch , its MAC address is shown in the table.why?

Comment: "Its" = the non-IP node one? No. If the first switch doesn't see a frame from that node, the second one can't see one either. Possibly that is a glitch in Packet Tracer, in reality it's impossible.